# Convert my Angular code to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have been coding Angular for about a year and I have made great progress. Now, everyone is shouting about TypeScript. There are numerous tutorials and blogs on the subject but there does not appear to be any consistency. How should this app.js file look in TypeScript?

```
angular.module('angular10App', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngStorage',
'cfp.loadingBar',
'ngAnimate'
])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And how should this controller look? I would prefer to keep scope out of it so lets assume I have 'Controller as vm' in the route config.

```
angular.module('angular10App')
.controller('ResultsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, results) {

    $scope.flightType = $stateParams.flightType;
    $scope.selectedAirportDep = $stateParams.from;
    $scope.selectedAirportRet = $stateParams.to;
    $scope.depDate = $stateParams.depDate;
    $scope.arrDate = $stateParams.arrDate;
    $scope.class = $stateParams.class;
    $scope.adults = $stateParams.adults;
    $scope.children = $stateParams.children;

    $scope.results = results;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration of a module is basically the same

```
angular.module('angular10App', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngStorage',
'cfp.loadingBar',
'ngAnimate'
])
.config($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
            $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
            $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

as for the controller, it should be defined as a class

```
module controllers {
    export interface IYourScope extends ng.IScope {
        someField: boolean;
        someOtherField: string;
    }

    export class yourController {
        constructor(private $scope: IYourScope) {
           $scope.someField = true;
           $scope.someOtherField = "something"; 
        }
    }
}
```

altough I like more to use the controllerAs and access then properties of the controller class (I guess it will lead to an easier migration later on to Angular 2.0), some something like:

```
module controllers {    
    export class yourController {

        public someField: boolean;
        public someOtherField: string;

        constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope)
           this.someField = true;
           this.someOtherField = "something"; 
        }
    }
}
```

then you can register this controller as always

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('ctrl',controllers.yourController);
```

Comment: Should the module be wrapped in something like: module app {}

Comment: It depends how you design your app, TypeScript isn't a seperate language, it's a superset over JavaScript, so you can use only parts of it and it will be ok. My approach is to have a bootstrap.ts file which has the module registrations. And don't forget to get the type definition files for angular.

Comment: Do you have any code on GitHub or BitBucket I could take a look at?